# A thought on Ancient Math

Tags: math-history

Is there a good site that I can see/ learn all the great work of mathematicians from all over the world? I am interested in reading those ancient book in a modern language. Suggestion? 
"Knowledge of Pascal's triangle has also been shown to have existed in China centuries before Pascal,[2] such as by Shen Kuo."~Wikipedia. 
Isn't it interesting? I think i will get inspired and enjoy at least some of the old theory.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Can you at least specify a period and country?

Comment: Well, I don't really know, any recommendation, Jack M.? What I was thinking was college classes teach you the mainstream ones, but there must be some cool math theory, tricks, ideas didn't teach you in school. Let's say overall non-European math based (maybe Chinese, Indian), since college is Eurocentric.

Comment: HSM (History of Science and Math) now has a bunch of good questions on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at :

- Benjamin Wardhaugh, [How to Read Historical Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140146) (2010)

supplemented with some historical surveys, like :

- John Fauvel & Jeremy Gray (editors), [The History of Mathematics : A Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0333427912) (1987)
- Jacqueline Stedall, [Mathematics Emerging : A Sourcebook 1540-1900](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199226903) (2008)
- Jacqueline Stedall (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of the History of Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199213127) (2009).

Then you cam move on to modern translation with commentary of ancient books/manuscripts, like :

- Jens Hoyrup, [Jacopo da Firenze's Tractatus Algorismi and Early Italian Abbacus Culture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764383909) (2007)
- Barnabas Hughes (editor), [Fibonacci's De Practica Geometrie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387729305) (2008)
- Muriel Seltman & Robert Goulding, [Thomas Harriot's Artis Analyticae Praxis : An English Translation with Commentary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387495118) (2007)
- Frank Swetz, [Legacy of the Luoshu : The 4000 Years Search For the Meaning of the Magic Square of Order Three](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814275) (2008)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a link to a timeline of mathematics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_mathematics

You can then search for the work of the individual mathematicians.

Or you could pick a topic and research its history, when I was younger I was fascinated with $\infty$ and I found it incredibly interesting how the concept was perceived and how it changed throughout history. [Cantor's work is awesome]